# Flow in pipe animation in JGraph/MXGraph

Tags: jgraph, mxgraph

Is it possible to make a **'flow in a pipe' annimation** in JGraph/MXGraph?

If yes, can someone post some instructions/MWE how to do this?

Comparable to this GoJS Example: http://gojs.net/latest/samples/processFlow.html

[image]

Comment: Here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBgxmz

Comment: Thanks for the CodePen example, but it doesn't work when the user moves one of the vertexes.

Comment: @WalterNorthwoods updated Codepen with your request http://codepen.io/anon/pen/worXjp